# use of inverted commas (" ") in sh command in jenkins file

Tags: jenkins, ssh, sh, scp

Hi i am using scp command in jenkinsfile via sh ' '.

My command is:

`sh 'sshpass -p "my-password" scp /home/jenkinshome.........'`

but it fails and in console output i find that inverted commas (" ") from the command is gone.
I am not sure what is happening there. Is there any othe way to pass my password.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that always works for me is I first create password less authentication between 2 servers where I want to scp. Works like a charm. No need to pass password.

Comment: I have heard about it but dont know how to do it, Do you have written down steps for this?

Comment: I think this should be a good start for you to understand the concept as well as create the SSH keys - https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/passwordless-ssh. Few more examples- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-passwordless-ssh-login/     https://youtu.be/NWuDfRDqjRs